# How to make MySQL table name case insensitive in Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mysql-workbench

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and MySQL 5.6 and I know database name and table name are case sensitive in Ubuntu (and some other *nix environments) by default.

Now, I want to make MySQL work as *case insensitive* in Ubuntu.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 61):

Open terminal and edit `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Underneath the `[mysqld]` section.add:

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Restart mysql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Then check it here:

```
mysqladmin -u root -p variables
```

Comment: You have to add this section if it is not available. Otherwise the restart will fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with MySQL 8.0 anymore. It has to be set before initialization.

Comment: I have installed the mysql as a contener with podman. As it turned out it has Oracle Linux Server 8.8 and mysql 8.1.0.  I needed to install vim (microdnf install -y vim) if I wanted a more powerful editor than cat and sed. But other answers suggest that it will be a pain.

Answer (score 14):

If you change `lower_case_table_names` in a DB with existing tables [Stack Overflow: MySQL > Table doesn't exist. But it does (or it should)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7759170/1744774) can happen.

[The comment to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24263629/1744774) helped me in this case:

> I reverted the value, restarted the database, exported the tables, set the value back to 1, restarted the database, re-imported the tables and everything worked again.

Comment: Happened to me and I wasn't aware that I have a max heart rate of 197 bpm ;-)

Answer (score 6):

This problem was causing pain for me, where Doctrine generated capital/CamelCase table names and MySQL stored them as lowercase!

It was solved by changing `my.cnf` and adding

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

under the [mysqld] section

my.cnf can be found:

- under LAMPP/XAMPP... :

  `/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`
- stand alone mysql server :

  `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Afterwards restart MySQL server, and everything will be ok.